# Rails caches_page, XML, and RESTful APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, rest, caching

My app exposes a RESTful API using map.resources (eg: map.resources :comments).  My comments controller caches_page :index, :show.  In this way, I expose an XML API, so that a Flex app can post new comments.  (eg POST to /comments.xml). This all worked fine until I enabled caching using the default filesystem store. Now, as far as I can tell, the cached file (/comments.xml) is generated, but any POSTs to /comments.xml hit the cached file rather than being routed into Rails and processed. If I delete the cached file, the first POST goes through (and then the cache is refreshed), but no more.

Is there a best-practices way of setting this up so that the POST will work? I could create a non-cached endpoint, but then the setup stops being intuitively RESTful.  Thoughts?